# Return Line Items Array from Zapier Code Block

Tags: javascript, zapier

Is it possible to return a `Line Items Array` from a Zapier JS Code Block?

I've read in the documentation that simply returning an array will cause future actions to run multiple times. In my situation though, I only want future actions to be run once but to be able to create `Line Items` in a future action.

For example, my input data contains an invoice amount. I am trying to create an invoice in Xero with a line for the sale, plus a line for the transaction fee which I calculate in the code block:

```
var invoiceAmount = inputData.new_charge_invoice_amount;
//Calculate fee
var transactionFee = (invoiceAmount / 100).toFixed(2);

output = [
  {
    description: "Subscription Charge",
    amount: invoiceAmount,
    account: 201
  },
  {
    description: "Fee",
    amount: transactionFee,
    account: 315
  }
];
```

Comment: Have you tried using line_items as a parent key? i.e. output= {line_items: [...]}

Comment: Yep! This is the correct answer, you should add it as an answer instead of a comment.